# TFS - is it possible to delete merge flag from files and send commit just like a normal changeset?

Tags: tfs, merge

Let's say I have two branches: A and child branch B. I wanna merge one changeset from branch A to B, but with one detail: I don't want flag [merge] for files in this changeset, it must look just like I edit files manualy and don't have a link on changeset from branch A. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the general idea is to generate a diff on the source branch with the following command

```
tf.exe diff [...] /recursive /format:unified /version:[...] >> diff.patch
```

Replace the `[...]` with the actual values (branch folder and versions). The documentation is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fd7dc73%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Then use the patch utility (from sourceforge.net) to apply it the other branch:

```
patch.exe -p0 < diff.patch
```

Then check in.